# Detection of syntax errors in bison with error production and YYERROR_VERBOSE macro

Tags: java, parsing, syntax-error, bison, transpiler

I made a java - phyton transpiler using the flex and bison tools. Bison rules refer to a restriction of Java grammar. I created an Abstract Syntax tree as an intermediate representation to manage the semantic analysis and the translation of a java source into pyhton. Everything works, but I would like some clarifications about the detection of syntax errors generated by bison. I used the YYERROR_VERBOSE macro and added the error production to detect the syntax errors on the braces and semicolons (using the related semantic actions yyclearin and yyerrok).
This is the complete parser: [parser.y](https://pastebin.com/9m1A9L5R)
This is a simple example of the java source:

```
public class ball{

   int b = 7;
   int a = 22;

   int operazione (){

      int f = 4;
      int g;

   }
}
```

If I make a syntax error on semicolons and braces, the error is correctly detected in the following way:

```
public class ball{

   int b = 7;
   int a = 22 //error here

   int operazione (){

      int f = 4 //error here
      int g;

   }
}

 Console: 
 >>Error: syntax error, unexpected INT, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 6
 >>Error: syntax error, unexpected INT, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 9
```

While for other errors, for example for round brackets, using the simple macro YYERROR_VERBOSE, they are detected in the following way:

```
public class ball{

   int b = 7;
   int a = 22 

   int operazione ){ //error here

      int f = 4 
      int g;

   }
}

 Console:
  >>Error: syntax error, unexpected RRBRACKET, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 6
  >>Error: syntax error, unexpected RRBRACKET alla linea 6
  >>Error: syntax error, unexpected LBRACE, expecting $end alla linea 6
```

Is the way Bison detects these errors with YYERROR_VERBOSE correct? Or are there any precautions that can be taken to improve the detection of them? (Avoiding to insert further error production)

EDIT:

I uploaded the new parser [Parser.y](https://pastebin.com/9m1A9L5R) and unlike the previous one I managed the NEWLINE token (\ n) (before it was ignored by the lexer). I modified the various productions by adding the NewlinePlus production (recursion of NEWLINE tokens) at the end of them.

This is the example:

```
 public class Stampa{ 

  int c  //error line 5

   int operazione (){ 

       int i [] = 5,54; //error line 7

       it b = 0; // error line 9

       for(i = 0; i < 5; i = i+ 1){

          System.println(i); //error line 13

          b = (i *3) + 1;
       }

       if( b > 8 ){ 

          int f = b 2; //error line 21

          System.out.println (f); 

       } else {

          float v = b  3; //error line 27

          System.out.println (v) ;

       } 

   return b // error  line 35
   }

}

public class Main {
  public static void main (String [] args){

     Stampa stringa = new Stampa () //error line 44
     stringa.operazione();
  }
}
```

These are the related errors detected with the new parser that manages the \ n:

```
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NEWLINE, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 5
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting NEW or LBRACE alla linea 7
Errore: syntax error, unexpected SEMICOLON, expecting COMMA or RBRACE alla linea 7
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting NEW alla linea 9
Errore: syntax error, unexpected PRINTLN, expecting OUT alla linea 13
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 21
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 27
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NEWLINE, expecting SEMICOLON alla linea 35
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NEWLINE, expecting SEMICOLON alla linea 44
```

These instead are the relative errors detected with the old parser:

```
Errore: syntax error, unexpected INT, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 5
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting NEW or LBRACE alla linea 7
Errore: syntax error, unexpected SEMICOLON, expecting COMMA or RBRACE alla linea 7
Errore: syntax error, unexpected ID, expecting SEMICOLON or COMMA alla linea 9
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting NEW alla linea 9
Errore: syntax error, unexpected NUMBER, expecting RBRACE alla linea 9
Errore: syntax error, unexpected SEMICOLON alla linea 9
Errore: syntax error, unexpected FOR, expecting $end alla linea 11
```

It would seem that error detection is more efficient with the parser that manages the \ n.

Is it correct to insert the end of line character (\ n) at the end of the productions or is it not usual compared to the previous parser which ignored the \n?

Comment: `YYERROR_VERBOSE` does not change the way errors are detected. It only changes how they are reported (that is, the message that is produced).

Comment: @rici If I left the syntax error detection as I did (YYERROR_VERBOSE to report all the other errors that are not detected by the error production, as in the last example shown), could it be considered a good error detection?

Comment: Verbose errors apply to all errors reported by a bison parser. The call to `yyerror` is made before the parser even knows that there is an applicable `error` production.

Comment: @rici Since this work is for a university exam, can the detection of syntax errors that I have adopted in the case of round brackets (last example shown on, therefore without error production) be considered a valid error detection?

Comment: Michele, if you are asking whether your grammar error rules are optimal, I'd say "no". They don't seem to me to show an understanding of the use of yyerrok and yyclearin, and there are far too many of them. But you seem to be fixating on the error messages. Those are fine, or as good as you will get with bison, except that your overuse of `yyerrok` results in an excessive number of error reports IMHO. But I'm not the one marking your assignment and I might have a very different sense of what is appropriate than whoever does mark it.

Comment: @rici So when should I use the yyerrok? Shouldn't it be used every time I have an error production? Based on what should be used?

Comment: This is an example in the bidon manual, so you can see the details there. Suppose you are writing an interactive line-by-line calculator. You use an error production synchronising on `\n` so that when a syntax error is detected, the rest of the input line is skipped. Since that's a perfect resynchronising strategy in this simple use case, you don't want to suppress error reports which occur very early in the next line. So you use `yyerrok`...

Comment: ...In genereal, you use `yyerrok` in cases like that, where you have definitely managed to reset the parse state after the error. In compilers, those cases are rare, and so is the use of `yyerrok`. `yyclearin` use cases are also quite rare, maybe even rarer.

Comment: The bison manual example is in section 2.3 but you should start [with section 2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Infix-Calc) to see the calculator without error productions, and then you'll see the motivation for the error production and the use of `yyerrok`. You could also read the [brief chapter on error recovery](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Recovery). This does not correspond with your style of writing error rules. In particular, it's rarely if ever useful to put `error` at the end of a production, or to have two of them in a production.

Comment: Another little thing: I think you'll find your error messages are more readable if you use [character literals](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-character-token) (like `'['`) instead of mysterious token names like `RRBRACKET`. If you rewrite both the scanner and the parser to use character literals, you would see errors like `syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ';' or ','`. Also see the use of *literal string tokens* as aliases, to give better names to your other tokens.

Comment: Thank you @rici ! One last thing: is it correct that in the case of the first example, errors are detected on row 6 instead of row 4 and on row 9 instead of row 8? That is, is it correct that the error messages always refer to the instruction following the one where the error is present?

Comment: That's one of the well-known issues with parsing error detection. Figuring out that the problem is a missing semicolon is a much harder problem than the one bison is trying to solve. The bison error detection algorithm only sees that the token which appears in the input cannot be shifted, and its response is to discard the token. If you try to guess that a token was missing and attempt to insert it, you could end up in an infinite loop of incorrect error recovery. This is all well discussed in the dragon book, which you should have been given as a textbook :-).

Comment: Hi @rici , I edited the question, could you kindly give me a new opinion?

Comment: you shouldn't do that sort of thing. This is not a chat board; it aims to be permanent resource of useful questions and their answers. But I'll let you off the hook this time since no-one answered your question, least of all me. To answer your new question, no that is not usual. If your rules all force recognition of a newline character, that means statements cannot span multiple lines, and that is far more of a nuisance than imperfect error messages. Remember that a compiler's first, second and third goals are to correctly process correct code. Error detection comes afterwards.